# Valid Flag disputed

Tags: discussion, flagging

I recently flag an answer as **not an answer**. I got surprise when it ended as **disputed**. It happened to me so many times that valid flag mark as **disputed**. What it does, it may remain the answer **undeleted**.

**Here is my flagged answer screenshot:**

[image]

**Here is flag result:**

[image]

Here is the question link: [Magento 2: Delete duplicate products programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203800/magento-2-delete-duplicate-products-programatically/297204)

I don't understand, how anyone mark this answer as `Looks OK` or valid. There should be better criteria of reviewing flags

Comment: Bad Low Quality Post reviewing seems to be a pattern on this SE site. I've documented a few more of these [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2688/) for additional data points. I will say that most of the reviewers are correctly doing their tasks, but the problem is that it takes only 2 of 5 people to say, "Looks OK." If this didn't happen frequently, I would have just custom flagged, but 10 posts being reviewed wrongly is evidence for a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you how someone can dismiss this. Someone does not read what is reviewing.
Thanks for pointing this. I've deleted it.

Comment: Thanks but it's not a permanent solution. There should be better criteria like reviewer auditing or specific keyword not allow in answer like `?` etc